# Magento2 Development Workflow ( Am I Crazy? )

Tags: workflow, magento2, development-environment

I'm working on a Magento site and have a question about the workflow in developer mode. I'm using a child theme named luma_child.

If I have a change to the file default.xml in the child theme folder, for this change to take effect does the following sound correct?

1. magento setup:di:compile - No changes show up unless I first run this( for xml files ) is this correct?
2. grunt exec:luma_child - I then have to run this to clear the previously cached files.. even though I thought it should be using symlinks and not copying the files?
3. grunt less:luma_child - Then the css needs to be regenerated since the files are cleared. ( side note, why doesn't grunt generate a static compiled version in the non-cache folder and cached folder so this can be symlinked and not have to rerun every time the var directories are cleared )

There is no way this is correct. Just want to know if other people had issues with this and found a solution to this horrible process.

Comment: I don't think you're crazy, it does have its caveats, are you on Windows by any chance ? If so, you might be seeing symlinks not working correctly

Answer (score 0):

You don't always need to execute the command **setup:di:compile** on developer mode.
For instance if you have installed a new Module or Plugin via Composer after running the upgrade command you need to generate that code and thus must run **setup:di:compile** 
This is widely discussed in this thread on Stackover, please  read  it throughly to grasp the concept.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184237/magento2-setupdicompile